# Display cross domain content in IFrame (IE8)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I realized that IE8 does not allow links from cross domains to be displayed in IFrame. 
It seems like there are only two Header options that Microsoft allows to modify.

1. `X-FRAME-OPTIONS : "DENY"`  (This does not display any IFrame content )
2. `X-FRAME-OPTIONS : "SAMEORIGIN"`  (Displays content from the same domain)

Is there a work around to allow content from other domains to be displayed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Point your source to an internal, dynamic (server-generated) page that simply proxies the external web page. I.E. You hit `src="myContent.asp"`, and you get `www.google.com`, or equivalent.

Comment: How do i get www.google.com to display in mycontent.asp? Wouldn't i be facing the same issue?

Comment: The server (and thus server pages), can make whatever requests to whatever they want without restriction. This is strictly a browser problem. I'd have to google for a cookie-cutter ASP solution, but the theory is sound.