# Twitter Problem in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, twitter

I am having this problem with the twitter button and IE 8(which problems IE 7 and I don't care for IE 6 anymore).

In short the problem is when I implement the tweet button, the rest of the text in a  does not show up. It works fine in Firefox and Safari and is just an IE problem. The current problem can be seen here on the last sample coupon, coupon 3.

http://www.ichibancoupons.com/?page=examples

The code generated for the Twitter button is:

```
<div class="right-coupon-twitter">
<iframe title="Twitter For Websites: Tweet Button" style="width: 110px; height: 20px;" src="http://platform0.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?_=1291080504828&amp;count=horizontal&amp;lang=en&amp;text=Sample%20Coupon%203%20Sample%20coupon%203%20provided%20by%20Ichiban%20Coupon%20%20Management.&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ichibancoupons.com" allowtransparency="true" tabindex="0" class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-horizontal" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
 </div><!-- coupon-twitter -->
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what is causing this problem and a solution?

Comment: couple 3 looks good for me, in IE8 (in both IE8 standard & IE7 standard mode). The text in that anchor is clean. Maybe you can give a screenshot?

Comment: Sure thing. I have a screen shot here:http://www.ichibancoupons.com/twitter_problem.html

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the fact that Iframes do not allow for cross domain content in IE8, a (somewhat dated) solution can be found here: [Display cross domain content in IFrame (IE8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448944/display-cross-domain-content-in-iframe-ie8)